# Petitions: check met and unmet ones

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

My people made too many `Petition`s one after another, and I didn't write them down on paper. Now I don't remember all of them and don't know what they are. There were some `Guildhall`s, and at least one `Temple`.

How can I check the list of `Petition`s?

**Version:** 0.50 (Steam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no intended ingame ways to check that. Most direct approach (as with many other interface and control deficiences) would be to use [DFHack and its `list-agreements` command](https://docs.dfhack.org/en/stable/docs/tools/list-agreements.html). There are other indirect ways, which *could* help, but are time-consuming. For example, accepting a petition generates a happy thought for the dwarf:

[image: She felt happy after the acceptance of a petition for a guildhall for The Guild of Cresting]

Likewise you can try to create a new guildhall. and when hovering over selections, you will find a number of members of this profession, and a established guild, if exist. Guilds without a guildhall are probably the ones who either requested a guildhall, or will do so soon.

Grand guildhalls requests are somewhat tricky to discern (except for happy thoughts), so it is better to upgrade all guildhalls as quickly, as possible, but if it isn't feasible, then upgrade largest guilds first. Checking thoughts of the dwarves of professions belonging to the largest guilds canhelp you here.

Temples are even more tricky, because sometimes 60-something large following of specific god are happy without a temple for years, but another god's requests a temple as soon, as there are 10 dwarves. Looking at thoughts is probably the best way here.

Comment: Do DFHack work together with the premium Steam version?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah yes, it lags few days behind new versions, but you can still play base game in those days. And it has a Steam page (be sure to read installation guide): https://store.steampowered.com/app/2346660/DFHack__Dwarf_Fortress_Modding_Engine/